# Merge csv files in one file

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

i have a set of csv files , i want to merge them in one csv file. ,it take some times ,but i don't find the file in the destination path

```
hdfs dfs -getmerge /DATA /data1/result.csv
```

Any help 
Thanks

Comment: Syntex hadoop fs -getmerge  <src> <localdst> check /data1/result.csy in Local Directory of your System

Answer (score 5):

> getmerge

**Usage:** `hadoop fs -getmerge [-nl] <src> <localdst>`

Takes a source directory and a destination file as input and concatenates files in src into the destination local file. Optionally `-nl` can be set to enable adding a newline character (LF) at the end of each file. `--skip-empty-file` can be used to avoid unwanted newline characters in case of empty files.

**Examples:**

```
 hadoop fs -getmerge -nl /src /opt/output.txt

 hadoop fs -getmerge -nl /src/file1.txt /src/file2.txt /output.txt
```

**Exit Code:**

Returns 0 on success and non-zero on error.

If some how it does not  work for you

**You can try cat command like this:** (If your Data is not large enough)

```
 hadoop dfs -cat /DATA/* > /<local_fs_dir>/result.csv

 hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal /<local_fs_dir>/result.csv /data1/result.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try concatenating the file in local linux fs using

```
cat $DOWNLOAD_DIR/*.csv >> $CONCAT_DIR/<concatenated_filename>.csv
```

And then put the concatenated file on hdfs.